# Push notifications works fine in development, but device not getting notification in production

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ok, so I have an app that is in the app store.  In development everything works fine I get all of the notifications that I send.  I should mention that we are using Firebase for analyics and push notifications as we have a iOS and Android version of the app.  Firebase account has both the correct development and correct production apns cert, the app's capabilities are set correctly to include push notifications and remote notifications in the background.

In the organizer window the entitlement for apns-environement is set to production whenever uploading to the app store or when exporting the app.  Whenever the app is first installed and ran the alert to allow push notifications is shown.  So my apns certs have to be configured correctly.
I am a working on contract for this company, just started 3 months ago, I would hate for these people to look at me in a bad light but I really don't know where the issue is.  I am also using Xcode's automatic code signing option, with the correct provisioning profile and developer account signed in the Xcode on this mac.

Comment: first thing is we cannot surely say that this is the problem, but in my experience this is the problem of either wrong way of generating the production apns certs or configuring the app with automatic code signing.

Comment: How could the generation of the production apns cert be done in a wrong way?  I checked the distribution cert being used when uploading to the app store and the keychain is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this and I do not know if you solved this,

I turned push off and deleted the certs from apple dev center and created them all over again and this made everything work as it should.

I also had this line of code set to,

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
```

I will change it to `.prod` when I push to the app store.