# What function receives push notifications in iOS from Firebase Messaging?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

A day ago the iPhones I'm using to test out push notifications were receiving push notifications but for some reason today they are not.

When it was working I would call the completion handler to present the notification in this function:

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

However, that function doesn't seem to be getting called anymore. The only function I see anything getting printed from is this one:

```
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

I got all of these functions from the [Firebase Send a Notification to an iOS Device docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device). All I really want is to be able to receive push notifications from Apples APNs server. I'm getting this line in my console `APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes` and also the push notifications were working yesterday so I'm not sure why it stopped.

The only thing I suspect made it stop working was that I deleted and reinstalled the app onto the iPhones, other than that I haven't messed with the code in the `AppDelegate` at all. Can anybody please help me figure out why my push notifications might have stopped being sent?

Note I'm using Firebase Messaging `topics` to send these out from my cloud function, which I can confirm is sending out the messages correctly as I'm receiving them in the 2nd function above, just not in the first one like it was received in yesterday. I'm using `admin.messaging().sendToTopic(pet_Id, payload, options);` to send out the notifications.

Here's my [full AppDelegate.swift file](https://gist.github.com/MarksCode/ed3e36c56c16f1cd901ae3bb0327a884), if anybody could help me figure it out I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something similar,

Here is my answer here - [Firebase Push Notifs Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39975090/5716449)

Here is what could be the problem,

*I turned push off and deleted the certs from apple dev center and created them all over again and this made everything work as it should.*

"*I also had this line of code set to,*

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
```

I will change it to `.prod` when I push to the app store."

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Above the line you added there's a comment that says `// With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.`. Did you turn off swizzling then?

Comment: I will have to check. I will try to see at the end of the day.